# java: string split loose last element

Tags: java, string

im sorry for the screen shot
the strange result for me,
while result of split does not contain the last element,

from my pov the correct result must be

['[','xtrue','']

am i right?

```
 public static List<String> splitString(String source, String delimiter) {
        if (Objects.equals(delimiter, "[")) {
            return Arrays.asList(source.split("\\["));
        }
        String[] sArr = source.split(delimiter);
        return Arrays.asList(sArr);
    }
```

sure, guess im not safe with split operator, but a little search on google do not solve my question how to use for get as i want

[image]

Comment: Add code as text not as image. An please add an [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

A per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

So the output is correct.

If you want trailing empty strings you'll have to use the [two-parameters version of `split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)) passing a negative integer as the second parameter, since

> If the limit is negative then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the [resulting] array can have any length

So, like you say in your own answer

```
source.split(delimiter, -1);
```

will include the empty string after the last `"` .

Answer (score 1):

for the community
the solution for my case

```
source.split(delimiter, -1);
```

thx